# Retrofit2 SSLHandshakeException

Tags: android, ssl, retrofit2, sslhandshakeexception

I use Retrofit2. Requests are no execute after adding on server side SSL. The method onFailure get next Throwable - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer.

Initialization Retrofit:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(InterfaceAPI.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

Comment: add timeout connection to your okhttp client

Answer (score 0):

```
OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
clientBuilder.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

client = clientBuilder.build();
```

Then use this client for retrofit